# Foundation 5 - Dropdowns not working properly

Tags: html, zurb-foundation

having some more issues with Foundation 5.

the dropdown menus: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html

even when using there download and copy pasting the code from their site, the drop down bar when refreshing the page or first load, shows the content already dropped down, and only disappears when you spam click it a few times and move the mouse away. is something broken with it, i assumed it was supposed to have the drop down content hidden on initial load.

code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Foundation | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
     <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="large-12 columns">

        <a href="#" class="button" data-dropdown="drop">Link Dropdown &raquo;</a>
          <ul id="drop" class="[tiny small medium large content]f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
            <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      $(document).foundation();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried using the scripts at the top and bottom of the page, same thing.

```
 <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

also is it possible instead of clicking to have it just display on mouse hover?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super-old question, but I got here via Google and wanted to answer it in case anyone else does.

At least one of your problems is this line

```
class="[tiny small medium large content]f-dropdown"
```

You're not supposed to literally put `[tiny small medium large content]`. You're supposed to choose one of those options (if desired). Like this:

```
class="tiny f-dropdown"
```